# Ruby, turn array of hashes into single hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following Array of Hashes:

```
a = [{:a => 1, :b => "x"}, {:a => 2, :b => "y"}]
```

I need to turn it into:

```
z={"x" => 1, "y" => 2}
```

or:

```
z={1 => "x", 2 => "y"}
```

Can I do this in a clean and functional way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Hash[a.map(&:values)] # => {1=>"x", 2=>"y"}
```

if you want the other way:

```
Hash[a.map(&:values).map(&:reverse)] # => {"x"=>1, "y"=>2}
```

incorporating the suggestion from @squiguy:

```
Hash[a.map(&:values)].invert
```

Comment: You can just use `invert` for the bottom example, since it will handle duplicate keys, but +1.